# How to use GIMP to add a rippling effect on just a section of a picture

Tags: gimp, effects, selections

I want to add a rippling effect for a selection. But every time I select an area and add this animation, the entire picture is affected.

How do I apply this effect just to the selection?

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is still unclear to me. what do you mean by "rippling" effect? the images you show does not have any? could you also show us a pic of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rippling filter acts on the *current layer*. Move your selection to its own layer.

1. Select the desired area
2. <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. `Exit -> Paste As -> New Layer`

Make sure that layer is selected when you run the filter.